# How do I map/create an entity class for a table which has only foreign keys in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following tables in my database (Postgres): `questions`, `responses` and `question_response`. 
There is a many to many relationships between questions and responses tables and I have created the entity classes for both of these relations. I now have to create an entity mapping for `question_respone` table which doesn't have any primary key.

I have read about using `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId`, however, I am not sure how do I map two foreign keys which are primary keys in two different classes using these annotations.

## Note:

updating the entities after implementing the changes mentioned in the comments

Thanks!

## questions.sql

```
CREATE TABLE questions( 
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    question VARCHAR(255)
);
```

## respones.sql

```
CREATE TABLE responses( 
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    response VARCHAR(255)
);
```

## question_respone.sql #

```
CREATE TABLE question_response(
    question_id bigint REFERENCES questions ON DELETE CASCADE,
    response_id bigint REFERENCES responses ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY ( question_id, response_id)
);
```

## Question.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="qid_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "qid_seq", sequenceName="questions_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "questionText")
    private String questionText;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<QuestionResponse> responses;

    public Question() {}

    public Question(String questionText) {
        super();
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return questionText;
    }

    public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }

    public List<QuestionResponse> getResponses() {
        return responses;
    }
}
```

## QuestionResponse.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question_response")
public class QuestionResponse {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne 
    private Question question;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne 
    private Response response;



    public QuestionResponse() {
        super();
    }

    public QuestionResponse(Question question, Response response) {
        super();
        this.question= question;
        this.response = response;
    }

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

}
```

## Response.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "responses")
public class Response {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="rid_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "rid_seq", sequenceName="questions_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "responseText")
    private String responseText;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "response", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<QuestionResponse> question;

    public Response() {}

    public Response(String responseText) {
        super();
        this.responseText = responseText;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getResponseText() {
        return responseText;
    }

    public void setResponseText(String responseText) {
        this.responseText = responseText;
    }

    public List<QuestionResponse> getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

}
```

# WildFly console #

```
13:54:49,581 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) Application run failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
 No identifier specified for entity: com.poc.questionnarie.QuestionResponse
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your Problem is. Your @Entitiy classes look good to me.

Comment: @larsgrefer I want to map the question_response table to an entity class, and I don't have a entity class for that yet since there is no primary key in question_response table and it contains two foreign keys which are mapped to primary keys of two different tables. So how do I go about creating an entity class which doesn't have an **Id**  and how do I use EmbeddedId or IdClass to create the **question_response.java** entity which maps to its corresponding table.

Comment: Okay. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @larsgrefer I need to query the question_response table and can't do that without having an entity class mapped to its relation in the database in JPA

Answer (score 3):

You can break up the many-to-many relationship into a one-to-many-to-one construct as described here:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional-with-link-entity

Comment: I tried the approach and I get the **Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity QuestionResponse** Not sure what I have to do next

Following is my QuestionResponse.java. I have also updated Question.java and Response.java accordingly  as  mentioned in the jboss user guide you posted

//Omitting getters and setters due to char limit in comments

`Entity
Table(name = "question_response")
public class QuestionResponse {
 Id
 ManyToOne 
 private Question question;
 
 Id
 ManyToOne 
 private Response response;`

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.0.1 which auto manages the JPA and Hibernate versions. When I deploy my war on WildFly 11 it show  **org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (background-preinit) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.6.Final**  which I think means Hibernate version 5.3.6

Comment: Please update your question with your current Entities

Comment: Done. I have two Ids int the entity QuestionResponse. But, I still get the No identifier specified for entity QuestionResponse error. Not sure what needs to be done. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong @Id annotation? Which class do you import?